# Failed to instantiate org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, spring-boot, apache-spark-sql

I am working Apache Spark Integration with Springboot and CassandaraDB. I provided following configuration file for configuring spark and cassandra db.

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class SparkConfig {


 private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardRestServicesApplication.class.getName());

 @Value("${spark.master}")
 private String sparkMaster;

 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
 private String cassandraKeyspace;

 @Value("${cassandra.table}")
 private String cassandraTable;

 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
 private String cassandraHost;

 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
 private String cassandraPort;

 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
 private String username;

 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
 private String password;


 @Bean
 public SparkConf sparkConf() {
     SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
             .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",cassandraHost)
             .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandraPort)
             .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username)
             .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password)
             .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
             .setMaster(sparkMaster)
             .setAppName("DashboardSparkService");
     return conf;
 }

 @Bean
 public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() {
     log.info("Connecting to spark with master Url: {}, and cassandra host: {}",
                sparkMaster, cassandraHost);

     JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf());

     log.debug("spark context created");

     return javaSparkContext;
 }


 @Bean
 public SparkSession sparkSession() {
     return SparkSession
             .builder()
             .sparkContext(javaSparkContext().sc())
             .appName("DashboardSparkService")
             .getOrCreate();
 }

 }
```

Here is my service:

```
  @Autowired
private JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext;

@Autowired
private TaskSummarySparkRepo taskSummarySparkRepo;

public int getAllOrders() {
    //JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = sparkConfig.javaSparkContext();
    return taskSummarySparkRepo.getAllOrders(javaSparkContext);
}
```

And here is my repo:

```
    @Service                                     
    public class TaskSummarySparkRepo {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String CassandraKeyspace;

    @Value("${cassandra.table}")
    private String CassandraTable;


    public int getAllOrders(JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext) {
          JavaRDD<TaskSummary> rdd = javaFunctions(javaSparkContext)
                    .cassandraTable(CassandraKeyspace, CassandraTable, 
                     mapRowTo(TaskSummary.class));

          return (int) rdd.count();
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, since its building successfully but when I am trying to run the jar it is giving following error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskSummarySparkService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javaSparkContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaSparkContext' defined in class path resource [com/spectrum/dashboard/config/SparkConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/network/util/ByteUnit
```

And when I try to run it as spring-boot application from sts, it gives following error:

```
    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaSparkContext' defined in class path resource [com/spectrum/dashboard/config/SparkConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext]: Factory method 'javaSparkContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/collect/MapMaker
```

EDIT:
Here is the pom file dependencies I am using for the project:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-mapping -->
    <!--   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is there any issue with configuration or is it because of some problem with dependency injection?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a classpath issue. What build tool are you using? Maven? Gradle? Post the dependency section. Do you have multiple Spark libs on the classpath?

Comment: I am using maven as a build tool. I have included spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector and spark-core dependencies in pom.

Comment: Spring-boot can't initialize the javaSparkContext bean which is present in the SparkConfig file. I have provided configurations for connecting to cassandra db and to connect to spark master in javaSparkContext object which looks fine. What could be the source of error?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` almost always points to a classpath issue. Your most recent one is referencing Guava, it's possible you have a spark / guava combo of dependencies that are incompatible with one another.

Comment: yes, its a dependency issue with guava. The logs says class not found for org/spark_project/guava/collect/MapMaker, but it is present in the maven dependencies.   
Mapmaker class is a part of  spark-network-common jar file which comes with spark-core dependency.
My question is, how come if a file is present in maven dependencies then too spring-boot is showing class not found during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved when I deleted existing maven repository and then performed maven install along with machine restart.

Answer (score 0):

try adding org.apache.hadoop 3.** library to dependencies